# Dynamically load form on click in laravel with get

Tags: php, jquery, forms, laravel, get

I want to load a form when a user clicks a button. My current solution works by pulling a pre-created form using .get() . My problem is that if the user types the url directly to where the form is located, they can see the form in raw html with no css. Is there a better way to dynamically pull a form or even maybe a way I can restrict a user from seeing the form if they directly type the url where the form is being pulled from. My current solution looks something like this:

```
$('#upload-photo').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    /// load the contact form using ajax
            $.get("http://pms.dev:8000/uploadphotoform", function(data){
                // create a modal dialog with the data
                $(data).modal({ 
                    closeHTML: "<a href='#' title='Close' class='modalCloseImg'>x</a>",
                    position: ["20%",null],
                    minHeight: '700px',
                    minWidth: '600px',
                    fixed: false,
                });
            });
});
```

I'm using larval 5 and SimpleModal js plugin for pulling the form.

Answer (score 0):

You could [check if the request is an ajax request](https://laravel.com/api/5.2/Illuminate/Http/Request.html#method_ajax) before returning the form:

```
Route::get('/uploadphotoform', function(){
    if(!Request::ajax()){
        abort(404);
    }
    return view('form');
});
```

If this doesn't work, make use you added a `use Request;` at the top of the file to use the `Request` facade.

But why would you like to load the form from an ajax request?

Comment: I'm going to test to see if this works! The reason I'm loading from ajax request is because I wanted to build the form separately and only have it show on the page when user clicks upload photo button. Is there a better way to accomplish this? I didn't just want to hide it then show it with css. Thanks, any feedback is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Hi, well actually I would have done that this way, why hiding it with CSS would be an issue?